# Interfaces and generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have the code:

```
Set<? extends Notifiable> notifiables;
```

Notifiable is an interface. I don't understand the difference between the above code and:

```
Set<Notifiable> notifiables;
```

If Notifiable was a class then I'd understand the difference, the first code would allow Notifiable and any subclass of Notifiable whereas the second code would only allow Notifiable (and not any subclasses)

As you can't have an instance of an interface, what can I add/etc to the set? 
It seems to me there are only two options, either anything that implements Notifiable (in which case how is that different to the first code), or only "instances of Notifiable" which can't exist and so therefore nothing (which is pointless and should throw a compile time error).

Comment: +1 good question, I was trying to get it to work, but am not able to do it myself either.

Comment: It seems like you are misunderstanding what the wildcard indicates. The wildcard doesn't have to do with what kind of `Notifiable` can be added to the set, but rather what kind of `Set` can be put in the reference variable. Actually you can't add anything to a `Set<? extends Notifiable>`.

Comment: @radiodef, I mean is the difference between a variable which is declared with the wildcard and the one without?

Answer (score 15):

A `Set<Notifiable>` *can* hold instances of classes that implement `Notifiable`.  It's not limited to holding only instances whose concrete type is `Notifiable` (and you're right, there's no such thing).  But a `Set<Notifiable>` guarantees that it can hold *any* kind of `Notifiable`, since it has an `add(Notifiable)` method that can accept anything that implements the interface.

Suppose that you have some classes called `Foo` and `Bar` which both implement `Notifiable`.  If you create a `Set<Foo>` — that is, a set that's *only* allowed to contain instances of `Foo` and its subtypes — you can't pass it to a method that takes a `Set<Notifiable>`, because that method may add things that aren't `Foo` instances, such as `Bar`.

```
public void addABar(final Set<Notifiable> notifiables) {
    notifiables.add(new Bar());  // OK, since Bar is a subtype of Notifiable
}

public void wontWork() {
  final Set<Foo> foos = new HashSet<>();
  addABar(foos);  // Compile error, can't convert Set<Foo> to Set<Notifiable>
}
```

But sometimes you want to write a method that *can* accept things like `Set<Foo>` and `Set<Bar>` in addition to `Set<Notifiable>`.  That's where the wildcard comes in.  A `Set<? extends Notifiable>` guarantees that everything in it is some kind of `Notifiable`, but it *doesn't* guarantee that every kind of `Notifiable` can be added to it; it's allowed to be limited to a subtype.  You can't call `add()` on it, because that method is now `add(? extends Notifiable)` instead of `add(Notifiable)` and you can't call a method whose argument type is unknown.

You'd typically use this when you don't need to add elements, but you do need to look at the existing elements and call `Notifiable` interface methods on them, and you want to allow the the caller to pass sets of subtypes such as `Set<Foo>`.

For example:

```
public void notifyAll(final Set<? extends Notifiable> notifiables) {
    for (final Notifiable notifiable : notifiables) {
        notifiable.notify();
    }
}

public void example() {
    final Set<Foo> foos = whatever();
    notifyAll(foos);  // OK, since a Set<Foo> is a Set<? extends Notifiable>
}
```

If `notifyAll()` took a `Set<Notifiable>`, you wouldn't be able to pass `foos` to it.

Comment: The question here however is, is there a `Set<? extends Notifiable>` that **can exist**? If you can find such a case, then I would gladly see it.

Comment: @skiwi, yes, every `Set<Notifiable>` is a `Set<? extends Notifiable>`.  So is every `Set<Foo>` and `Set<Bar>`.

Comment: The key difference is that a `Set<Foo>` is *not* a `Set<Notifiable>`, since it doesn't support methods like `add(Notifiable)` that can be used to add a `Bar`.  But it *is* a `Set<? extends Notifiable>`, since that doesn't require it to support adding other kinds of notifiables.

Comment: I'm on my phone and have only skimmed your answer. But it seems like your talking about adding sets to sets?

Comment: @Jonathan., no, adding individual items to sets.

Answer (score 6):

Let's use a more straightforward example:

```
Set<? extends Serializable> serializables;
```

This one declares a variable which can hold a reference to a `Set` of `Integer`s, `Float`s and so on:

```
 serializables = new HashSet<Serializable>(); // valid
 serializables = new HashSet<Number>(); // this is valid as well
 serializables = new HashSet<Integer>(); // valid
```

This one on the other hand:

```
Set<Serializable> serializables;
```

can only hold a `Set` of `Serializable` objects however:

```
serializables = new HashSet<Serializable>();
serializables = new TreeSet<Serializable>();
```

so this one will be a compiler error:

```
List<Serializable> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**Corollary:**

If you want a field which can hold ***any subtype of*** `Notifiable` then use:

```
Set<Notifiable> notifiables = new HashSet<Notifiable>();
```

if you want to ***restrict the subtype of `Notifiable` which can be used*** then this is the way to go:

```
Set<? extends Notifiable> notifiables = new HashSet<MyNotifiable>();
```

**Addendum:**

This is perfectly legal so you can retrofit your `Set` later as you see fit:

```
Set<? extends Notifiable> notifiables = new HashSet<NotifiableA>();
notifiables  = new HashSet<NotifiableB>();
```

Comment: `Number` isn't an interface, though, so this doesn't really address the question.

Comment: Same stands for interfaces.

Comment: Of course you can add any subtype of `Set<Notifiable>` to this data structure as I've said in my answer. Edited it to clarify the issue.

Comment: `Set<? extends Notifiable> notifiables = new HashSet<MyNotifiable>();` why not just have MyNotifiable in the variable declaration? Also I don't see how that limits it to MyNotifiable? I thought type checking was just done on variable declarations?

Answer (score 0):

For one-level of generics in Collection types, the role of the `? extends` wildcard is not very significant because all Collection methods look like

```
E get(int index);
boolean add(E e);
```

which are effectively the same as:

```
? extends E get(int index);
boolean add(? extends E e);
```

due to Java sub-type polymorphism rules.

However, the wildcard is significant when the sub-type rules come into play:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1);
    List<? extends Number> numSubTypeList = list; // Works
    List<Number> numList = list; // Illegal
```

Similarly for Multi-level generics:

```
    Collection<Collection<Number>> col1 = new ArrayList<Collection<Number>>();
    col1.add(list); // Illegal

    Collection<Collection<? extends Number>> col2 = new ArrayList<Collection<? extends Number>>();
    col2.add(list); // Works
```

However, even `col2`'s signature is not suitable for generic libraries. Those will probably expect `Collection<? extends Collection<? extends Number>>`, which `col2` is sub-type.